# If pressure inside a container is lesser than atmospheric pressure, how long can the vessel resist deformation?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure

Is the strain caused by stress (due to the pressure difference) is negligible?

Comment: Please read the posting guidelines - then think a bit about what it means for a material to have structural strength.

Comment: How can a gas bottle have 6000psi inside without exploding?

Comment: @JonCuster - they have to be strong bottles....

Comment: Well, for vacuum not all that strong mind you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main failure mode for vessels under external pressure is the so-called buckling (loss of stability) (see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YfMoxfuR3Og ). The critical pressure differential for buckling depends on the shape of the vessel, its material, and thickness. So in your case the pressure differential is less than critical, so there is no buckling.

Answer (score 0):

Your question will probably be closed, but a brief suggest that might help answer it is that it is possible to make metal containers that will never deform even though they contain vacuum and this is the case with many pieces of scientific equipment - e.g. electron microscope.

Your question is unanswerable without knowing the shape/material/dimensions etc of the container, but even if we did know those details it would be really complicated to calculate it and off-topic for this site because it would be an engineering question.